# add set values together in a dataframe cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, set, series

I have a data frame with a set as one of the column. I am trying to add the values of the set together and create a new column. Any ideas ?

input Dataframe:

```
1     {0.4154521378005839, 0.5341809649069569, 0.35...  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
3     {0.31367362283294203, 0.37413260754622946, 0.... }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
4     {0.38943794667290854, 0.37413260754622946, 0....}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
5     {0.31367362283294203, 0.3816072438174095, 0.4...}
```

Output Dataframe:

```
1     {0.4154521378005839, 0.5341809649069569, 0.35...  }   1.29                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
3     {0.31367362283294203, 0.37413260754622946, 0.... }    0.68                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
4     {0.38943794667290854, 0.37413260754622946, 0....}     ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
5     {0.31367362283294203, 0.3816072438174095, 0.4...}     ...
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.Series.apply` with built-in `sum`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sets': [{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}]})

df['sum'] = df['sets'].apply(sum)

print(df)

        sets  sum
0  {1, 2, 3}    6
1  {4, 5, 6}   15
2  {8, 9, 7}   24
```